# css selector select only the first child text and not the div

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-scraping

I want to use css selector to select only the text (which is in my example "1.42") from this div`<div class="one">` for scraping purpose:

```
<div class="one">
1.42
<div class="nested">..</div>
</div>
```

I tried this but return the whole `<div class="one">` (and I want only the text):

```
div.one:first-child
```

and this also:

```
div.one:first-child:not(.nested)
```

They all return the text plus the content inside `div.nested`

**EDIT:**

I want to use the selector to scrape the specific text using Beautifulsoup

```
soup.select_one('div.one:first-child:not(.nested)')
```

Comment: what you want to do with that text? hide it?

Comment: no use it with Beautifulsoup for scraping

Comment: I see that my answer below doesn't take into consideration that you probably can't edit the external html file, so if you could clarify what kind of outcome your soup.select_one test gives it would be helpful. Edit: You already wrote what it is, sorry about that. Afraid I can't help then. Is it possible in Beautifulsoup to strip the whole inner div.nested from the result with a function?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot css-select something that isn't inside of a html tag with or without a css class. In your case you should wrap your 1.42 text in a html tag, like a `<p>`.

That is also best practice, never to print text directly within a div, without a semantic text tag like a p.

Once you have your `<p class="...">Text here</p>` you can select div:first-child or simply select the p or `p.theclassname`. Another method is `div:nth-child(1)`.